# SPARK SCALA Stream ? in output

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following:

```
val partials = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, iter) => {
val (keys, values) = iter.toSeq.unzip  
val sums  = values.scanLeft(0)(_ + _) 
Iterator((keys.zip(sums.tail), sums.last))   
})

partials.collect
```

results in:

```
res12: Array[(Seq[(String, Int)], Int)] = Array((Stream((c01,1), ?),10), (Stream((c05,5), ?),18), (Stream((c08,8), ?),27))
```

My question is: what does the "?" represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream lazily evaluates its content (can be infinite) and memoizes visited part. Elements before `?` represents already seen items, `?` represents the part of the `Stream` which hasn't been evaluated yet.

```
scala> val s = Stream.continually(1)  // Infinite stream of ones
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> s  // Only the head of the stream is known
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> s.take(3).foreach(_ => ())  // Evaluate the first three elements

scala> s  // Now you the first three elements are known
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 1, 1, ?)
```

Comment: practically speaking that is

Comment: From readable representation? Not more than from any other `toString` implementation. It is designed for quick visual inspection during interactive development. All it does is reflect Stream semantics.